# How to connect to the localDB by using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I think there are some function lost in the VS. After I right click on the Server Explorer, there only exist "Copy", "Refresh" and "Properties".

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xat1/v/t34.0-12/12067145_1084577254886171_1366454821_n.jpg?oh=ccedd46483b1524bfe1f7a0438ff5826&oe=5614769F&**gda**=1444187729_4d955b88b786c25e62c7d02fc95e1d67](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xat1/v/t34.0-12/12067145_1084577254886171_1366454821_n.jpg?oh=ccedd46483b1524bfe1f7a0438ff5826&oe=5614769F&__gda__=1444187729_4d955b88b786c25e62c7d02fc95e1d67)

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal I have attached a link of my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you no need to right click on the table name, should  right click on db name "user-pc\localdb......" and connect

Comment: I have tried it, but the right click menu also show as same as the above image.

Comment: In server explorer window, in the top there are some option icons. (refresh, connect to database, connect to server, etc ). Through those options, you can connect by clicking connect to database icon.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate solution:**

Download SQL Server Data Tools in visual studio.

After Installation you can see "Server object explorer" - Same Like "Server explorer" in your vs.

Now, you can view your database and all other properties.

**Link** : 
[Download Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/jj650015)

**Note:** You may not find SQL Server Data Tools For 2010. (Available sources are 2012 and 2013)

Still look at this, [Step wise solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/02/installing-and-using-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-on-visual-studio-2010-and-vwd.aspx)